npm fails to install Parcel locally on Windows
My package.json looks like this (partially):
{
    "browserslist"   : [
        "> 1%"
    ],
    "dependencies"   : {
        "bootstrap": "^5.3"
    },
    "devDependencies" : {
        "parcel": "latest",
        "rimraf": "^6.0",
        "sass"  : "^1.81"
    },
    "source": ["src/scss/main.scss", "src/scss/other.scss"]
}

Every time I try to install, I get this dump of errors:
npm warn cleanup Failed to remove some directories [
npm warn cleanup   [
npm warn cleanup     '\\\\?\\F:\\path\\to\\my\\project\\node_modules\\@parcel\\watcher',
npm warn cleanup     [Error: EBUSY: resource busy or locked, rmdir 'F:\path\\to\\my\\project\node_modules\@parcel\watcher'] {
npm warn cleanup       errno: -4082,
npm warn cleanup       code: 'EBUSY',
npm warn cleanup       syscall: 'rmdir',
npm warn cleanup       path: 'F:\\path\\to\\my\\project\\node_modules\\@parcel\\watcher'
npm warn cleanup     }
npm warn cleanup   ],
npm warn cleanup   [
npm warn cleanup     '\\\\?\\F:\\path\\to\\my\\project\\node_modules\\@parcel',
npm warn cleanup     [Error: EBUSY: resource busy or locked, rmdir 'F:\path\\to\\my\\project\node_modules\@parcel\watcher'] {
npm warn cleanup       errno: -4082,
npm warn cleanup       code: 'EBUSY',
npm warn cleanup       syscall: 'rmdir',
npm warn cleanup       path: 'F:\\path\\to\\my\\project\\node_modules\\@parcel\\watcher'
npm warn cleanup     }
npm warn cleanup   ]
npm warn cleanup ]
npm error code 1
npm error path F:\path\to\my\project\node_modules\lmdb
npm error command failed
npm error command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node-gyp-build-optional-packages
npm error 'node-gyp-build-optional-packages' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
npm error operable program or batch file.

I'm deleting node_modules (and package-lock.json) before I run npm i. I ran npm cache clean --force. I opened Windows Terminal as administrator. Nothing works. Interestingly, I have no issue installing Parcel globally, but running it globally is another matter. Maybe that's an issue for a separate question, but if you wish to know, when I install it globally and try to run parcel build, it says there are "no entries". If I run parcel build src/scss/main.scss src/scss/other.scss I get farther, but it fails to resolve relative paths to Bootstrap's SCSS files. For example, I have this in main.scss:
@use "variables";
@use "functions";

@use "bootstrap/scss/bootstrap-grid" as twb-grid with (
    $grid-breakpoints : variables.$grid-breakpoints,
    $grid-gutter-width : variables.$grid-gutter-width,
    $container-max-widths : variables.$container-max-widths,
    $spacer : variables.$grid-gutter-width,
);

It complains that it can't find the stylesheet. I was able to install Parcel locally in the past on other projects without any problems and I didn't get these errors when I ran parcel build. Please help!
